# Compile elasticsearch in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch, gradle, compilation

I am new to gradle and have cloned Apache elasticsearch project. I have been struggling with it for the last 3 days and could no get it to compile in eclipse. I want to run it and debug the code to know how it works. I have been successful in compiling in the terminal but could not get it done in eclipse.
Steps i have tried so far:

1. Ran gradle eclipse in terminal and imported it as an existing project        in eclipse. Now it starts building workspace but i still cannot run the     ElasticSearch.java class's main method. It says no main type available.
2. Imported the project as a gradle project but then it throws an exception of "unable to resolve DependencySubstitutions which is a class in gradle core jar.

Exception it throws while converting it to gradle project.

```
startup failed:
build file      '/Users/rakshitsareen/Development/elasticsearch/build.gradle': 141: unable  to resolve class DependencySubstitutions 
 @ line 141, column 47.
rategy.dependencySubstitution { Dependen
                             ^

1 error

Could not fetch model of type 'HierarchicalEclipseProject' using Gradle   distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-bin.zip'.
```

Exception it throws while building the project

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'elasticsearch'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: No. gave up ...

Answer (score 0):

(note: I have to work on that a bit more. It has worked at some point, now it isn't)

I know your question is two years old and it was not about elasticsearch 6.x, however a search engine brought me here and since I struggled a bit before getting elasticsearch and eclipse and gradle to work, here my notes:

Take elasticsearch's [contributing readme](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) serious, it says (for elasticsearch 6.x):

> For Eclipse, the minimum version that we support is Eclipse Oxygen (version 4.7).

Before using eclipse, let gradle build some things for eclipse:

`git/elasticsearch $ ./gradlew eclipse`

This should result in `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Now go to `Help->Eclipse_Marketplace` and search for `buildship`. Install it - it enables the gradle support in eclipse.
Now `File->import->gradle` and choose the directory of your elasticsearch's git repo. When the window `Import options` shows, tick `Override workspace settings` and point the `Java home` to your java 11 installation (e.g. "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"), it will not compile with a java version before that.

If a popup appears 'Groovy developer tools needed' (or so), click on `show solutions`, this will bring you to the marketplace and show the `groovy dev` plugin. Install it.

That's it!

You can see the tabs "Gradle tasks" and "Gradle executions", here you can execute tests, see problems etc. You can got to the source and have code assistant. You can set breakpoints and happy debug.

Note: at least for me things take their time, especially since eclipse and the gradle-wrapper eat 4 GB of RAM, bringing my system into swapping. But be patient, it shall work at the end.